# Взаимодействие процессов Linux. Алгоритм Банкира С++

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность, ос

необходимо реализовать взаимодействие нескольких процессов в Linux с помощью алгоритма банкира исходя из представленного псевдокода:

```
**begin integer array Заем, Требование, Клиент_Сем,
Клиент_Пер, Номер_Талера,
Возвращенные_Талеры[1..N],
Талер_Сем, Талер_Пер,
Номер_Клиента[1..M];
integer Взаимн_искл, наличные, k;
boolean procedure Попытка_выдать_талер_клиенту (integer j);
begin
if Клиент_Пер[j]=1 then begin
integer i, Своб_Деньги;
boolean array Заверш_под_сомн[1..N];
Своб_Деньги :=наличные -1;
Требование[j]:=Требование[j]-1;
Заем[j]:=Заем[j]+1;
for i:=1 step 1 until N do
Завершен_под_сомн[j]:=true;
L0: for i:=1 step 1 until N do begin
if Завершен_под_сомн[j] and
(Требование[i]=<Своб_Деньги) then begin
if i<>j begin
Заверш_под_сомн[i]:=false;
Своб_Деньги:=Своб_Деньги+Заем[i];
goto L0;
end
else begin
i:=0;
L1: i:=i+1;
if Талер_Пер[i] = 0 then goto L1;
Номер_Талера[j]:=i;
Номер_Клиента[i]:=j;
Клиент_Пер[j]:=0;
Талер_Пер[i]:=0;
Наличные:=Наличные-1;
Попытка_Выдать_Талер_Клиенту:=true
V (Клиент_Сем[j]);
V (Талер_Сем[j]);
goto L2;
end;
Требование[j]:=Требование[j]+1;
Заем[j]:=Заем[j]-1;
end;
Попытка_Выдать_Талер_Клиенту:=false;
L2: end /* процедуры */
Взаимн_искл:=1; Наличные :=M;
for k:=1 step 1 until N do begin
Заем[k]:=0;
Клиент_Сем[k]:=0;
Клиент_Пер[k]:=0;
Требование[k]:=Потребность[k];
Возвращенные_Талеры[k]:=Потребность[k];
end;
for k:=1 step 1 until M do begin
Талер_Сем[k]:=0;
Талер_Перем[k]:=1;
end;
parbegin
Клиент 1: begin ... end;
…
Клиент i: begin ...
P(Возвращенные_Талеры[i]); P(Взаимн_искл);
Клиент_Пер[i] := 1;
Попытка_выдать_талер_клиенту(i);
V(Взаимн_искл);
P(Клиент_Сем[i]);
…
end;
Талер 1: begin ... end;
Талер m: begin integer h;
…
начало: P(Талер_Сем[m]); P(Взаимн_искл);
Требование[Номер_Клиента[m]] := Требование[Номер_Клиента[m]] - 1;
Талер_Перем[m] := 1;
наличные := наличные + 1;
V(Возвращенные_Талеры[Номер_Клиента[m]]);
for h:=1 step 1 until N do begin
if (Попытка_выдать_талер_клиенту(h))
then goto выход;
end;
выход:V(Взаимн_искл);
goto начало
…
end;
parend;
end;**
```

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define CLIENTS 3 //N
#define THALERS 5 //M
using namespace std;

int loan[CLIENTS], request[CLIENTS], need[CLIENTS], client_var[CLIENTS], thaler_num[CLIENTS];
int thaler_var[THALERS], client_num[THALERS], cash;

pthread_t client_thread[CLIENTS];
sem_t client_sem[CLIENTS], thaler_sem[THALERS], returned_thalers[CLIENTS];
sem_t exclusion;

bool Try_to_give_thaler(int j);



int main()
{
    sem_init(&exclusion, 0, 1);
    for(int k = 0; k < CLIENTS; k++)
    {
        loan[k] = 0;
        sem_init(&client_sem[k], 0, 0);
        sem_init(&thaler_sem[k], 0, 0);
        request[k] = need[k];
        sem_init(&returned_thalers[k], 0, request[k]);
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < THALERS; k++)
    {
        sem_init(&thaler_sem[k], 0, 0);
        thaler_var[k] = 1;
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < CLIENTS; k++)
    {
        sem_wait(&returned_thalers[k]);
        sem_wait(&exclusion);
        client_var[k] = 1;
        pthread_create(&client_thread[k], 0, &Try_to_give_thaler, &k);
        sem_post(&exclusion);
        sem_wait(&client_sem[k]);
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < THALERS; k++)
    {
        sem_wait(&thaler_sem[k]);
        sem_wait(&exclusion);
        request[client_num[k]] -= 1;
        thaler_var[k] = 1;
        cash += 1;
        sem_post(&returned_thalers[client_num[k]]);
        for(int h = 0; h < THALERS; h++)
        {
            if(Try_to_give_thaler(h))
            {
                sem_post(&exclusion);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool Try_to_give_thaler(int j)
{
    if(client_var[j] == 1)
    {
        int spare_money;
        bool Finish_not_defined[CLIENTS];
        spare_money = cash - 1;
        request[j] -= 1;
        loan[j] += 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < CLIENTS; i++)
        {
            Finish_not_defined[i] = true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < CLIENTS; i++)
        {
            if(Finish_not_defined[i] && request[i]<=spare_money)
            {
                if(i != j)
                {
                    Finish_not_defined[i] = false;
                    spare_money += loan[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    L1: i += 1;
                    if(thaler_num == 0)
                    {
                        goto L1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        thaler_num[j] = i;
                        client_num[i] = j;
                        client_var[j] = 0;
                        thaler_var[i] = 0;
                        cash -= 1;
                        sem_post(&client_sem[j]);
                        sem_post(&thaler_sem[j]);
                        return true;
                    }
                    request[j] += 1;
                    loan[j] -= 1;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Нужна помощь в реализации.
Результат сборки и доп описание псевдокода на скриншоте.

[image: Сборка]
[image: Сущность задачи]

Answer (score 1):

Просто чтобы всё компилировалось можно сделать обёртку функции `Try_to_give_thaler` для **Pthread**.

```
// структура для входных/выходных данных нити с главным процессом
struct  st_Try_to_give_thaler {
  int arg ;
  bool  result  ;
} ;

bool Try_to_give_thaler ( int ) ;

// обёртка вашей функции с нужными аргументами
void * th_Try_to_give_thaler ( void * s ) {
  st_Try_to_give_thaler * st = ( st_Try_to_give_thaler * ) s ;
  st -> result = Try_to_give_thaler ( st -> arg ) ;
  return s ; }

struct  st_Try_to_give_thaler thread_link[CLIENTS];
thread_link[k].arg = k ;
// даём процессу адрес структуры
pthread_create(&client_thread[k], 0, &th_Try_to_give_thaler, (void*)&(thread_link[k]));
результат брать здесь : thread_link[k].result
```